# SSGHelpers and GetStaticProps question regarding params

Tags: typescript, next.js, getstaticprops, trpc

I am trying to use createProxySSGHelpers to prefetch data with trpc in a project I'm working on, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why I cannot get my id from url params is coming back undefined when I can see it in my url bar.

Here is my getStaticProps which is trying to prefetch:

```
import { generateSSGHelper } from "~/server/helpers/ssgHelper";
import type { NextPage, GetStaticProps } from "next";

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const ssg = generateSSGHelper();


  const householdId = context.params?.householdId;

  if (typeof householdId !== "string") throw new Error("No householdId.");

  await ssg.household.getHouseholdInfo.prefetch({ householdId });

  return {
    props: {
      trpcState: ssg.dehydrate(),
      householdId,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = () => {
  return { paths: [], fallback: "blocking" };
};
```

and here is my SSG helper function:

```
import { createProxySSGHelpers } from "@trpc/react-query/ssg";
import { appRouter } from "~/server/api/root";
import { prisma } from "~/server/db";
import superjson from "superjson";
import { type Session } from "next-auth";

export const generateSSGHelper = () =>
  createProxySSGHelpers({
    router: appRouter,
    ctx: { prisma, session: null },
    transformer: superjson, 
  });
```

and my trpc router call:

```
getHouseholdInfo: protectedProcedure
    .input(z.object({ householdId: z.string() }))
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const userId = ctx.session.user.id;

      return ctx.prisma.household.findUnique({
        where: {
          householdId: input.householdId,
        },
        select: {
          name: true,
          members: true,
          invitedList: true,
          householdId: true,
          _count: true,
        },
      });
    }),
```

The error is thrown on the if (typeof householdId !== "string") throw new Error("No householdId.") line, and if that's removed it says that undefined is unabled to be serialized as json.  Am I grabbing the params incorrectly or am I missing something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks mostly correct, what is your file structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think that householdId can be `string | string[] | undefined` so maybe that's why the if is not working.

Try to do:

```
 const householdId = context.params?.householdId as string;
```